# Covariant derivative on principal bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, connections, principal-bundles

I know that there exists a connection on a principal bundle and via parallel transport it is possible to define a a covariant derivative on the associated bundle.

However, can we also define a covariant derivative on the principal bundle. I.e. something that can differentiate a section along a vector field? Or do we need a linear structure like the one in a vector bundle to 'take derivatives'?

Comment: Since the fibers of a principal bundle don't (generally) have a vector space structure, it doesn't really make sense to define a covariant derivative since we can't define typical properties we'd like to have for a derivative, e.g. linearity and being a derivation over tensor products.

Comment: One can define a "derivative" of sections of a principal $G$-bundle $\pi:P\to M$, but the derivative of a section will be a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued one form, rather than a $P$-valued one-form.

Comment: If $E \to B$ is a fiber bundle with connection $\mathcal{H}$, $\psi$ is a local section around $x\in B$, and $v \in T_xB$, set $\nabla_v \psi$ as the vertical component of ${\rm d}\psi_x(v)$. But this doesn't have nice properties, really...

Comment: You can use parallel transport to define the covariant derivative of a section as follows: Let $P$ be a principal $G$-bundle over $M$ and $s: M \rightarrow P$ be a section. Given $p \in M$ and $v \in T_pM$, let $c: I \rightarrow M$ be a curve such that $c(0) = p$ and $c'(0) = v$. There is a unique parallel section $\tilde{c}: I \rightarrow P$ along $c$ such that $\tilde{c}(0) = s(p)$. There is a unique map $g: I \rightarrow G$ such that $s(c(t)) = \tilde{c}(t)g(t)$. You can now define $$\nabla_vs(p) = \tilde{c}'(0) + pg'(0) \in T_{s(p)}P$$

Comment: @Deane. Thanks. But as J.V.Gaiter noted, such a covariant derivative is not linear, or is it?

Comment: @NicAG For any of these definitions, the map $(v,s)\mapsto\nabla_vs$ will be linear in $v$, but it's meaningless to refer to such a map as "linear in $s$", since there is no notion of addition or scalar multiplication for sections of a principal bundle.

Comment: I see what's going on. I've always considered the terms connection and covariant derivative to be synonymous and well-defined on both vector and principal bundles. But it appears that the term covariant derivative is reserved for a connection that is a linear differential operator.  As @Kajelad points out, this makes sense only if the fibers of the bundle are vector spaces and the fibers of a principal bundle are not vector spaces.

Comment: They are synonymous, but from another perspective. If you view both concepts to introduce a notion of "what is parallel to $M$", then they translate into one another in a compatible way. A curve in a $\gamma:I\to P$ principal bundle $P\to M$ is parallel to $M$ if its tangent vector at each point $t\in I$ is horizontal, that is, in the connection forms local kernel. In a vector bundle $E\to M$, a curve $\gamma:I\to E$ being parallel to $M$ is formalized by it covariant derivative to vanish. So the association of covariant derivatives to connection forms of the respective frame ...(continued)

Comment: bundle and, vice versa, the association of connection forms to covariant derivatives on an associated vector bundle just translates these notions of parallelity into one another. Viewing this in a local trivialization may be instructive. Then in both cases one (locally) has a notion of trivial covariant derivative/connection form, that is, a distinguished choice of parallelity, and these do translate into one another (a local section in $P$ induces a local frame in an associated vector bundle, a local frame of $E$ is a local section in the frame bundle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from my point of view what a covariant derivative should be or should do I'd say that indeed you need a linear structure.

So in principle, when passing from simply vector space-valued functions $M\to W$ (or sections in the trivial bundle $M\times W$, resp.) to sections in a not-necessarily trivial bundle $E\to M$ with fiber-type $W$ you run into troubles defining a derivative of such functions. Usually this is paraphrased as that it is intrinsically "not possible to compare points in different fibers". However, it is possible to chose a covariant derivative, and thereby (at least locally) a frame which is "constant" or parallel to $M$ (cf. my comment above). Once you everywhere have distinguished such a notion of parallelity you can now indeed take derivatives and view it as "how a function changes compared to what we call constant", which is of course just the action of the covariant derivative. For this notion you need a vector space structure.

On the other hand, on a principal bundle you also have a notion of parallel in the sense of everywhere horizontal but as you don't have a vector space structure in the fibers, so "comparison with a constant section" works a bit different, particularly not by something having similar properties as a derivative in the above sense. Rather would you do something like @Deane in the comments above, but I'd say this is not a "derivative" in the sense of what a derivative should do.

Answer (score 0):

It is defind in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_covariant_derivative) as $D\phi(v_0,...,v_k)=d\phi(hv_0,...,hv_k)$ where $h$ is the projection to horizontal subspace according to the given principal connection of the principal G-bundle $\pi:P\to M$.

If $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ is a representaion of $G$ on some vector space $V$, then a tensorial (or basic, i.e. G-equivariant and horizontal) k-form of type $\rho$ on $P$ can be identified with $P×_\rho V$-valued k-form on M.

As other answers/comments said, it is not a covariant derivative in the common sense, but is a covariant derivative in the sense that if $\phi$ is a $P×_\rho V$-valued k-form on M, and it is identified with tensorial form $\hat\phi$ on $P$, and $\nabla\phi$ is $P×_\rho V$-valued k+1-form on M, where $\nabla$ is the covariant derivative on $P×_\rho V$ corresonding to the given principal connection, and $\widehat{\nabla\phi}$ is the identification of $\nabla\phi$ to tensorial form on $P$, then $D\hat\phi=\widehat{\nabla\phi}$.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that there exists a connection on a principal bundle and via parallel transport it is possible to define a a covariant derivative on the associated bundle.

Ehresmann connections are the geometric version of connections. They are generally available on all fibre bundles and not just principal bundles. Let $p:E \rightarrow M$ be a fibre bundle over the base $M$. Then an Ehresmann connection is a splitting of $TE$ into 'horizontal' and 'vertical' bundles. The vertical bundle is given as $VE:=ker(Tp)$. Thus the splitting is reduced to a choice of horizontal bundle $HE$ which is complementary to the vertical bundle, ie $TE=HE\oplus VE$. This can be encoded into a projection $C:TE \rightarrow TE$ whose image is exactly $VE$ and whose kernel is $HE$. It also means that $C \in \Omega^1(M,TM)$. This is what is called a tangent bundle valued 1-form.

Now it is often stated that a connection is not covariant, for example see the many general relativity texts. And this, whilst true, is not the whole picture. The connection is not covariant when it is considered to live on the base manifold. It is, however covariant, as the construction above manifestly shows, when it is where it should be on, on the total space. When we specialise the above construction for the tangent bundle this means a connection lives on the second tangent bundle.

Secondly, parallel transport is more or less the same as an Ehresmann connection. We don't use parallel transport to 'transport' our connection from the principal bundle to an associated bundle, but through *inducing* it on the associated bundle. This relies on the action of the gauge structure group on a standard fibre, in this case, this will be a vector space and so a representation of the gauge structure group.

I'm using the term gauge structure group for what is called the structure group in the mathematical literature and what is known as the gauge group in the physics literature. It seems useful to have such a term to show the parallels between the two in two different languages but also to disambiguate since the gauge group is also, confusingly, used for a different but related and much larger group.

> However, can we also define a covariant derivative on the principal bundle. I.e. something that can differentiate a section along a vector field? Or do we need a linear structure like the one in a vector bundle to 'take derivatives'?

Yes, you can. It is called the covariant exterior derivative. There is one on the principal bundle and also on any induced associated bundle and they are connected through a canonical isomorphism. Fix a connection $C$ as above on a principal bundle $P$ and define $C^*: \Omega(P,V) \rightarrow  \Omega(P,V)$ by $(C^*\alpha)_p.(v_1,...,v_k) \rightarrow \alpha_p(Cv_1,...,Cv_k)$. Here $C^*$ is a projection onto the space of horizontal forms which is actually independent of the connection (it is the counterpart of the vertical bundle defined above, but because it is in the cotangent bundle, it is now horizontal). We now define the covariant exterior derivative:

> $\nabla^C:\Omega^k(P,V) \rightarrow  \Omega^{k+1}(P,V)$

> by $\nabla^C:=C^* \circ d$.

Now fix a representation of $G$ on a vector space $V$. Then there is a canonical isomorphism:

> $q^{\sharp}:\Omega(M,P[V] \rightarrow \Omega_h(P)^G$

We also have a covariant exterior derivative $\nabla^V_C$ induced on the associated bundle $P[V]$ and they are connected as:

> $q^{\sharp} \circ \nabla_C =   \nabla^V_C \circ q^{\sharp}$

The details are in section 11 of Kolar, Michor & Slovak's *Natural Operations in Differential Geometry*.